# Multivariate (Lebesgue) Integration of Composition

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, lebesgue-integral

$A,B$ are blocks in $ \mathbb{R}^n$, and $f: A \rightarrow B$ a continuous map,  such that $ ||f(x)-f(y)|| > c||x-y||$ for all $x,y \in A $ and some $c>0$. If $g: B \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is integrable. Prove that $g\circ f:A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is integrable.

My approach is since $f$ is continuous then the set $D_f$ where $f$ is not continuous is empty so $D_f$ has null measure and $D_g$ is integrable then $D_g$ has also null measure. As $D_{g\circ f}\subset D_g\cup D_f$ then $D_{g\circ f}$ has null measure. By Lebesgue's Theorem $g\circ f$ is integrable.

Comment: You are mixing up Lebesgue and Riemann integrals. It is not true that continuous functions are Lebesgue integrable (when the domain is not known to be bounded)  so your argument is not valid.

Comment: it's missing one more hypothesis that A and B are blocks in $\mathbb{R^n}$

Comment: But the question is about Lebesgue integration. Since the functions are not given to be bounded  you cannot use continuity to get integrability. In particular, it is not given that $g$ is  a bounded function,

Comment: The hyphotesis above $g$ is that $g$ is integrable. By definition $g$ has to be bounded.

Comment: I've found the same question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2463714/fx-fy-ge-cx-y-with-c0-then-for-gb-to-mathbbr-integrable-the?rq=1